# How to i update a component using addComponent in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am trying to update a existing component in this below code snippet, where "**index**" is index of existing component.

```
    TextField l = new TextField();
    l.setText(txt);
    t.addComponent(index, l);
```

From the above, new component is being added at the end instead of updating to that indexed component. How we can achieve updating the existing component ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the old component then add the new component or use `Container.replace()`.